# radio button assignment as a search filter

Tags: django, search, variable-assignment

Template:

```
<form method="POST" action="/Bycategory/">
<input type="radio" name="andor1" value=1 checked>
<input type="radio" name="andor1" value=2>
<select id="pathology_id" name="pathology_id">
    {% for pathology in pathology_list %}
        <option value="{{ pathology.id }}">{{ pathology.pathology }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

There are actually three search selects(pathology, commodity,
technology)  The user can do and/or for a mix or match of the three,
which is why I need the and/or option in the views.py.

The views.py:

```
def Bypub(request):
    andor1 = request.POST['andor1']
    pathology_id = request.POST['pathology_id']
    p = get_object_or_404(Pathology, pk=pathology_id)
    pub1=Publication.objects.exclude(pathpubcombo__pathology__id= 1).filter(pathpubcombo__pathology=p)
    list=[]
    andlist=[]
    for publication in pub1:
        if andor1 == 1:
            if publication not in list:
                list.append(publication)
        if andor1 == 2:
            if publication in list:
                andlist.append(publication)
                #list=andlist
    return render_to_response('search/categories.html', {
        'andor1' : andor1,
        'pub1': pub1,
        'pathology': p,
        'list' : list,
        'andlist' : andlist,
    },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

I know that all my code works without error, but the line (if andor1
==1:) and (if andor1 ==2:)
is being ignored.  I suspect that the value for andor1 does not appear
at the point where I'm using it.  I think it doesn't actually render
until after the return render_to_response, because it appears in the
next template as a value, otherwise I would see some kind of response
at the if andor1 ==1: in the template.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you!  The quotes worked.  My thinking was stuck on the fact that the value was a numeric and shouldn't need quotes, so I didn't try that.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `andor1` is a string when passed from the HTML form and `"1" == 1` is False in Python. Try the following:

```
try:
    andor1 = int(request.POST['andor1'])
except (KeyError, ValueError):
    andor1 = 0
```

Now it's an integer and your checks below (`if andor1 == 1`) should succeed.

Alternatively test for strings:

```
if andor1 == "1":
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The dpaste code:  http://dpaste.com/10899/

Comment: Please edit your question: Use an indentation of 4 spaces for code examples.

Comment: You can easily achieve this by selecting the code in the EDIT text field and hitting Ctrl+K